# How to format input data for denoising signal using LSTM-RNN?

Tags: lstm, recurrent-neural-network, noise

I have an noisy input data and it's corresponding Ground Truth values for each timestep. The values are floats. Basically the input and output data is in the form of 1D array of floats. I want to train the LSTM network to de-noise the input data. How should I format my data for the RNN?

I tried the formatting that we use to do in case of forecasting time series, i.e,
[[1], [2], [3], [4]] -> [5]
[[2], [3], [4], [5]] -> [6]

But I couldn't find anything specific in case of noise removal.